# Como mantener el estilo y formato en excel desde python

Tags: python, excel, formato

Hola buenas noches a todos. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Excel y Python. En este caso tengo que hacer algunas modificaciones a un archivo xlsx. Pero este archivo viene con cierto formato y estilo en cada una de sus hojas. El problema lo estoy teniendo al salvar el archivo estoy perdiendo el formato original, y se muestra todo como si fuera en texto plano. Aquí tengo una fracción del código.

```
import openpyxl as xl
*#Abrir archivo* 
wb = xl.load_workbook("CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127.xlsx") 

*#...
#...
# Aquí se trabaja el archivo 
#...
#...*

*#Salvar el archivo luego de las modificaciones.*
wb.save("CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127.xls")
```

Entonces como decía, luego de salvar el archivo estoy perdiendo el formato y el estilo. Acá algunas imágenes para evidenciar el problema.

Archivo original
[image: Archivo original] 
Luego de salvar el archivo
[image: Luego de salvar el archivo]

Aquí muestro otro ejemplo.

Esta es otra hoja el archivo original. 
[image: Esta es otra hoja el archivo original.]
Luego de salvar el archivo
[image: Luego de salvar el archivo]
Entonces si alguien tiene una idea de cómo mantener el estilo del archivo se lo agradecería muchísimo. Gracias

Comment: ¿Has probado a guardar el archivo en .xlsx en lugar de .xls? En cualquier caso, si se trata de un bug, yo miraría https://www.xlwings.org/

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, ok revisare y te aviso como me fue

Comment: Revivo el post ya que cuento con la misma duda. Pudiste solucionarlo?